# Text classifier training data not properly loaded via spacy debug-data CLI

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface, spacy

## Background

I am trying to train a `multiclass` (Labels are mutually exclusive) text classification model in Spacy in a Google Colab notebook.
The classes are

- POSITIVE
- NEGATIVE
- NEUTRAL

I formed the training data to the annotation format specified [here](https://spacy.io/usage/training#training-simple-style)

The following is a sample of annotations I made

```
[.
.
["Happy #MothersDay to all ... ", {'cats': {'NEUTRAL': 1.0}}],
["Happy mothers day ..", {"cats": {"POSITIVE": 1.0}}],
.
.]
```

## Problem

When I try to debug my data using the [debug-data](https://spacy.io/api/cli#debug-data) option in spacy CLI with the following command (done in a Jupyter notebook)

```
%%bash
(python -m spacy debug-data en \
    /content/drive/My\ Drive/Spacy/Pretrained/train_clas.json \
    /content/drive/My\ Drive/Spacy/Pretrained/eval_clas.json \
    -p 'textcat' \
)
```

I get the following output

```
=========================== Data format validation ===========================
✔ Corpus is loadable

=============================== Training stats ===============================
Training pipeline: textcat
Starting with blank model 'en'
0 training docs
0 evaluation docs
✘ No evaluation docs
✔ No overlap between training and evaluation data
✘ Low number of examples to train from a blank model (0)

============================== Vocab & Vectors ==============================
ℹ 0 total words in the data (0 unique)
ℹ No word vectors present in the model

============================ Text Classification ============================
ℹ Text Classification: 0 new label(s), 0 existing label(s)
ℹ The train data contains only instances with mutually-exclusive
classes.

================================== Summary ==================================
✔ 2 checks passed
✘ 2 errors
```

It could not read the data properly but I have checked the files and I have atleast 1000+ samples like above.

Links to [train](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11mS0YumLqcwo2LDrfq6vjVwPcSWCct1h) and [eval](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11gJvrZOksAax5f_42KIKHCAYa68luj4T) jsons.

I can not find any error in my data, Can someone point to the error?, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spacy debug-data` command expects data in spacy's internal JSON training format, described here: https://spacy.io/api/annotation#json-input

There are some examples here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/master/examples/training/textcat_example_data . The conversion script in the same directory shows how to convert from a JSONL format that's very similar to the `TRAIN_DATA`-type format used in the example scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Adding latest debug data command for reference

```
!python -m spacy debug data ./config.cfg
```